# VBA send email in outlook 2016 efficiency worsened?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

There is a simple piece of standard VBA code that I use to send emails by looking through a list and generating around 2000 email to the draft folder.  In my old version of excel & outlook 2012, it took only around 20 min or less to generate all.  But after migrated to versions of 2016, the same piece of code take up to 4 hour.  Is there any way to speed it up? Thanks!

```
Function CreateEmail(ToSend As String, ccs As String) As Integer
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olemail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutlookTemplate As String
    OutlookTemplate = "TemplatePath.oft"

    Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olemail = olapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(OutlookTemplate)  

    Dim recipientCheck As Outlook.recipient


    With olemail          
        .HTMLBody ="Body String"
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sender email address"
        .Subject = "subject string"
        .To = ToSend
        .CC = ccs
        .Attachments.Add "attachment.pdf" ' pdf size is 200k

        'this is a check for tosend email addresses, 
        'already tried remove this piece of code, no significant improvement there
        Dim recipient As Variant
        Dim i, j As Integer
        For Each recipient In .recipients
            recipient.Resolve
        Next

        .Save
    End With

    CreateEmail = 1
End Function
```

Comment: Note that `Dim i, j As Integer` will declare `j` as `Integer` but `i` as `Variant` in VBA you need to declare a type for **every** variable `Dim i As Long, j As Long`. But actually here you can remove it, because both variables are not used at all.

Comment: Can you post the code for the function that calls `CreateEmail`?

Comment: Thank you Peh! i just removed dim i, j in the code, :) They are used for another piece of code that i've identified and isolated with the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, in the code each time you create a new Outlook `Application` instance. You can optimize the codebase by extracting such pieces into separate methods (outer) that may call the `CreateEmail` multiple times only for creating items.

```
Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Set olapp = New Outlook.Application

Function CreateEmail(app as Outlook.Application, ToSend As String, ccs As String) As Integer
    Dim olemail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutlookTemplate As String
    OutlookTemplate = "TemplatePath.oft"
    Dim recipientCheck As Outlook.recipient

    Set olemail = olapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(OutlookTemplate)  
    With olemail          
        .HTMLBody ="Body String"
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sender email address"
        .Subject = "subject string"
        .To = ToSend
        .CC = ccs
        .Attachments.Add "attachment.pdf" ' pdf size is 200k

        'this is a check for tosend email addresses, 
        'already tried remove this piece of code, no significant improvement there
        Dim recipient As Variant
        Dim i, j As Integer
        For Each recipient In .recipients
            recipient.Resolve
        Next

        .Save
    End With

    CreateEmail = 1
End Function
```

You may also find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)